# How can I see list of dropped columns?

Tags: python

```
for i in df_train:
    if df_train[i].isnull().sum()>10000:
        df_train.drop(columns=[i],inplace=True)
```

How can I see which columns I dropped with this code?

Answer (score 1):

First off - avoid using a for-loop and break it up into separate parts.

First get your null counts in one go,

```
null_counts = df_train.isnull().sum()
```

Then filter to get the columns to drop - this'll give you a `Series` of columns and their actual counts for reference.

```
to_drop = null_counts[null_counts > 10000]
```

Then finally drop those columns using the `.index` property of the above:

```
df_train.drop(columns=to_drop.index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, 
null_counts = df_train.isnull().sum()
to_drop = null_counts[null_counts > 10000]
drop_columns = to_drop.index
drop_columns.tolist()
with those codes, I solved my problem.